# How to join 4 tables in mysql for getting different colums data on same html table?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Image of what I want from 4 tables:

[image: Image of what I want from 4 tables]

As You can see there are

- 1.com_name
- 2.emp_type_name
- 3.loc_name

3 different tables with their primary keys: `com_id`,`emp_type_id` and `loc_id`.

Now, there is master table called `organization_tbl` and it is having `org_id`. `org_id` is FK in all the tables.

I want to display `com_name` from `company_tbl` of `org_id=1` `emp_type_name` from `emp_type` table where `org_id=1` and `loc_name` from `location_tbl` where `org_id=1` in where clause if I put `organization_tbl.org_id=1` then this should be the output have to come but i got below output duplicate values.

[image: duplicate values]

```
SELECT emp_type.emp_type_name,location_tbl.loc_name,company_tbl.com_name
from organization_tbl  
left outer join company_tbl 
  on company_tbl.org_id=organization_tbl.org_id 
left outer join location_tbl 
  on  location_tbl.org_id=organization_tbl.org_id
left outer join emp_type
  on emp_type.org_id=organization_tbl.org_id
 GROUP BY   emp_type.emp_type_name,location_tbl.loc_name,company_tbl.com_name,
where organization_tbl.org_id=1
```

This is my query that not working as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just looks like your `WHERE` is in the wrong place to me:

```
SELECT 
    employer.emp_type_name,
    location.loc_name,
    company.com_name

FROM organization_tbl organization

LEFT JOIN company_tbl company
  on company.org_id=organization.org_id 

LEFT JOIN location_tbl location
  on  location.org_id=organization.org_id

LEFT JOIN emp_type employer
  on employer.org_id=organization.org_id

WHERE organization.org_id = 1

GROUP BY   
    employer.emp_type_name,
    location.loc_name,
    company.com_name
```

Comment: its also gives me all duplicate records as i mention the image above. i want only particular records from 3 tables . thanks for your reply anyways